# How can I connect to a network folder with VBS - with a prompt for the computer name first?

Tags: windows, networking, scripting, vbscript, windows-xp

I have been searching on SO and google all this afternoon to try and figure this out,

I would like to have a .vbs script that prompts me to enter the computer name e.g PC123
and then connect to the computer's C Drive (\PC123\c$) and open a windows explorer window using the required login credentials (that will be the same format for every computer)

ie:

Username: PC123\PC123_ADMIN

Password: PC123#ADMINpass

This is what I have currently:

```
Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "R:", "\\PC123\C$", False, "PC123\PC123_ADMIN",     "PC123#ADMINpass"
```

This works to connect and map R: to the pc I want,but has to be hard coded to one spesific computer, and does not allow for me to enter the computer I wish to connect to.

If possible I would like to just open an explorer window to the C$ directly as I would need to connect to a varying number of computers.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option might be to start `explorer.exe` directly with the UNC path (if the user runing the command has access to the share):

```
computer = InputBox("Enter computer name")
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "explorer /e,\\" & computer & "\C$", 1, False
```

**Edit:** If you have to pass credentials, stick with what you have and just replace the static computer name with a variable:

```
computer = InputBox("Enter computer name")
path     = "\\" & computer & "\C$"
username = computer & "\" & computer & "_ADMIN"
password = computer & "#ADMINpass"

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "R:", path, False, username, password
```

You can open an explorer window with that drive letter the same way you could with an UNC path:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "explorer /e,R:\", 1, False
```

Comment: This is great! 
Only is there anyway to automatically pass the local admin credentials to the computer using the "computer" variable?

ie the username and password are always in the same format for every remote computer:

username: computername_Admin
password: computername#ADMINpass

Comment: No. If you have to pass credentials, mapping the share to a drive letter is the only way that I am aware of. Of course one could come up with something using `runas.exe` and typing in the password via `SendKeys()`, but I'd strongly advise against such a hack, because it's ugly, insecure, and likely to break.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to be able to remotely access the computers without having to enter the username/password every time, but it seems like this is the best option, cheers!

Comment: You should be able to access remote admin shares without having to provide credentials when the local and remote admin user have the same name and password. In any other case you have to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the InputBox function.  It'll prompt you for a value.
E.g.

```
Input = InputBox("Enter your computer name")
```

To open the mapped drive in explorer, use Run.  E.g.

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
oShell.run "start R:"
```